# How to put icon in <ul> tag?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I would like to put `<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" style="color:red"></i>`  as my list-style-image. But instead of image I want to use the exclamation icon. How do I put the exclamation mark icon as the in the listing style ? At which part should I change and put the icon. If it is possible to do that. I'm using a bootstrap but I'm trying to change this part only.

How do I achieved it if I have these as CSS ?

```css
ul.listing-style2 li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.listing-style2 li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  content: "\f05d";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #106eea;
  font-size: 22px;
}
ul.listing-style2 li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
ul.listing-style2.modify li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
ul.listing-style2.modify li:before {
  content: "\f05d";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<ul class="listing-style2 modify ml-20 mb-28">
  <li>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut <i><b>labore et dolore magna.</b></i></li>
  <li>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just change the content to `content: "\f06a";` and the `color: red` to the same code. You can use `list-style: none` to the `<ul>` so that you won't get a redundant bullet.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.listing-style2 li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.listing-style2 li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  content: "\f06a";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
}
ul.listing-style2 li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
ul.listing-style2.modify li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
ul.listing-style2.modify li:before {
  content: "\f06a";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="listing-style2 modify ml-20 mb-28">
  <li>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut <i><b>labore et dolore magna.</b></i></li>
  <li>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</li>
</ul>
```

If you just want to put `!` mark as bullet. Change content to `content: '!'`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.listing-style2 li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
ul.listing-style2 li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  content: "!";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
}
ul.listing-style2 li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
ul.listing-style2.modify li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
ul.listing-style2.modify li:before {
  content: "!";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="listing-style2 modify ml-20 mb-28">
  <li>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut <i><b>labore et dolore magna.</b></i></li>
  <li>Change in the volume of expected sales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing lit, sed do eiusmod data tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.</li>
</ul>
```